# How to make half circle in open frameworks?

Tags: geometry, openframeworks

i'm newbie in open frameworks. 
I want to change my circle pattern to half circle. 
I used ofCircle( float x, float y, float radius ) function. 
I searched various answers and recommended to use ofBeginshape(), ofEndShape(), and ofVertex() function using iteration.

But i don't know how to use these functions and i need examples.. 
can you show me any examples of making half circle?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation ? http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/ or the tutorials ? http://openframeworks.cc/tutorials/

Comment: yes, i look around the tutorials, but as you know there are too many information for newbie.. :-( and i have no time.. can you show any example?

Comment: ofSetPolyMode(OF_POLY_WINDING_NONZERO);
ofBeginShape();
  ofVertex(400,135);
  ofVertex(215,135);
  ofVertex(365,25);
  ofVertex(305,200);
  ofVertex(250,25);
ofEndShape(); 

in this example, is the first line( ofsetpolymode )  necessary ?

Comment: i don't understand the role of curveto function,with these 3 parameters. can you make me sure to know this function? I want to make half circle pattern and i think this can be possible with making arc shape whose angle will be 0~180. But i am struggling in calculating the angle with multiplization with cos and sin, can anybody hely me?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it's clear, complete, and comprehensible. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there's nothing unclear about this question

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [`ofPath`](https://openframeworks.cc/documentation/graphics/ofPath/) and draw an arc, like this:

```
ofPath path;
path.moveTo(300 + 200, 300);
path.arc(300, 300, 200, 200, 0, 180);
path.setFilled(false);
path.setStrokeWidth(1);
path.draw();
```

This will draw a half circle at (300, 300) with a radius of 200px